# Run package.json scripts using grunt-maven-plugin

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs, npm

I have added the following in package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
```

I am using grunt-maven-plugin to run the goals of npm and grunt like this :

```
<pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>pl.allegro</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            grunt-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.5.1,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                create-resources
                                            </goal>
                                            <goal>npm</goal>
                                            <goal>grunt</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
```

Now I will want that I am able to run the npm start script in using the goals or somehow using Grunt. How is it possible to do so .

I understand that there is a plugin for typescript for grunt .. but I wanted to know how I can run this npm start using Grunt?

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    org.apache.maven.plugins
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    maven-war-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>
                                    [2.1.1,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                              <goal>exploded</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>pl.allegro</groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    grunt-maven-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>
                                    [1.5.1,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>
                                        create-resources
                                    </goal>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                    <goal>grunt</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hmm, is this really inside `<pluginExecution>`? You should have the `grunt-maven-plugin` defined in a `<plugin>` element. If so, could you post that instead?

Comment: how does that matter ?

Comment: It actually means everything :). So I'm guessing there is no `<plugin>` section with the grunt-maven-plugin defined then, correct?

Comment: sure there is a <plugin> wrapper above this

Comment: Then please post that. `<pluginExecution>` is only there to tell M2Eclipse to not raise an error when it encounters an execution of a plugin that is unknown to it.

Comment: pasted the whole <plugin> wrapper

Comment: Ah, there was a misunderstanding then. Do you have a `<build><plugins><plugin>` element with the `grunt-maven-plugin`?